# How to fix NoMethodError undefined method `escape' for URI:Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm following this [guide](https://www.davidangulo.xyz/simple-paypal-checkout-in-ruby-on-rails-using-orders-api-v2/) for implementing the PayPal REST API in my Rails app, and it gives an error that's said in the title, specifically pointing to this line in the code under `create_order`.

```rb
response = @client.execute request
```

I'm sure I have my client id and secret copy pasted and I also copy pasted most of the code to avoid any errors. What's causing this problem and how do I fix it? I appreciate the help.

Edit:

Command line output:

```
Started POST "/create_order" for ::1 at 2021-11-16 21:21:07 +0800
Processing by BookingsController#create_order as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1603)



NoMethodError (undefined method `escape' for URI:Module):

app/controllers/bookings_controller.rb:35:in `create_order'
```

Comment: Where is that coming from? Update with the error trace.

Comment: There's no error trace from the command prompt but I see errors in the browser's console. Should I post that one?

Comment: Post anything you have, otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: Updated. There are also a bunch of errors after it. The errors appear after I click either Paypal buttons.

Comment: That's not helpful. Update with the server error logs and the action that triggers it.

Comment: I replaced it with the command line output. There's no error trace though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to just do a monkey patch with future expectation of moving away from paypal-checkout-sdk (it's deprecated)

monkey patch option can be found at:
[paypal-checkout-sdk breaks in ruby 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67929562/paypal-checkout-sdk-breaks-in-ruby-3-0-1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33724456)

Answer (score -1):

you are missing gem files which are required to use the URI.escape

add these gems in you gemfile

- gem 'uri'
- gem 'net-http'
- gem 'http'

after that
run command =>  "**bundle install**" in the terminal

and then try to run you application via **rails s**

hope this will fix your error

Since "URI.escape" is depriciated by the ruby community but "paypal-checkout-sdk" uses it while requesting from client.
which is like this: @client.execute request